# How to set flag value in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

My code is :

```
<%@flag=0%>
<%if !@current_users_challenges.blank?%>    
                <%@current_users_challenges.each do |k|%>
                        <%@flag=0%>
                        <%match_results_comfirmation_loop=match_results_comfirmation%>
                         <%for j in 0...match_results_comfirmation_loop.size%>
                                    <%if k.created_at < match_results_comfirmation_loop[j].updated_at%>
                                            Agree Disagree <%= match_results_comfirmation_loop[j].updated_at.localtime.strftime("%A %d  %B %Y %I:%M %p")%>
                                            <br>
                                            <%match_results_comfirmation=match_results_comfirmation.drop(j+1)%>
                                    <%else%>        
                                            <%@flag=1%>
                                            <%break%>
                                    <%end%>

                                    Flag <%=@flag%>
                                    <br>
                                    <%if @flag==1%>
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^666
                                    <%else%>
                                    ***************************
                                    <%end%>
                         <%end%>

                <%end%>
        <%end%>
```

Even if I assigned value =1 to @flag and then breaking the loop but still my flag value remains zero. I am not able to understand why this is happening. And want to set the value to 1 so what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: You're breaking from the iteration before showing the value.

Comment: I want a flag value outside of that loop for If condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem then I removed @ symbol from veriable name and workrd for  me.
So you could try below code :

```
<%flag=0%>
<%if !@current_users_challenges.blank?%>    
            <%@current_users_challenges.each do |k|%>
                    <%flag=0%>
                    <%match_results_comfirmation_loop=match_results_comfirmation%>
                     <%for j in 0...match_results_comfirmation_loop.size%>
                                <%if k.created_at < match_results_comfirmation_loop[j].updated_at%>
                                        Agree Disagree <%= match_results_comfirmation_loop[j].updated_at.localtime.strftime("%A %d  %B %Y %I:%M %p")%>
                                        <br>
                                        <%match_results_comfirmation=match_results_comfirmation.drop(j+1)%>
                                <%else%>        
                                        <%flag=1%>
                                        <%break%>
                                <%end%>

                                Flag <%=flag%>
                                <br>
                                <%if flag==1%>
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^666
                                <%else%>
                                ***************************
                                <%end%>
                     <%end%>

            <%end%>
    <%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The control is not reaching where you are showing the value of `@flag`. Not sure but you code could be something like:

```
<% for j in 0...match_results_comfirmation_loop.size %>
    <% if k.created_at < match_results_comfirmation_loop[j].updated_at %>
        Agree Disagree <%= match_results_comfirmation_loop[j].updated_at.localtime.strftime("%A %d  %B %Y %I:%M %p") %>
        <br>
        <% match_results_comfirmation=match_results_comfirmation.drop(j+1) %>
        ***************************
    <% else %>
        <% @flag = 1 %>
        Flag <%= @flag %>
        <% break %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The point here is you are getting out of the loop before displaying the value, when your `@flag` is 1. So, you need to manipulate your code in according to execution control.